# Is there a way to get bing and google news search as rss?

Tags: rss, bing, feed, google-news

Is there a way to get Google and Bing news searches as RSS?

I'd like to have the most recent at the top of the results (ordered by time) if possible.

And show 100 results if that is possible.

I found this for Google, but it only shows 5 items or so, not that great.

https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=politics

I just want to search their news categories and get results as RSS.

Comment: did you find how to load 100 results

Comment: @chovy : Such a pitty :-| 10 results is not that great.

Comment: I resorted to scraping instead.

Answer (score 8):

You are right that Google no longer publicly shows RSS feeds for News searches. But there's a basic URL format that should continue to work.

If my search topic is "education", my search URL should look like:

```
https://news.google.com/news/section?cf=all&ned=us&q=education
```

Replace:

- value of `ned` (probably stands for 'news edition'), i.e. `us` with the appropriate country code that's relevant to you. E.g. `uk` (not `gb` for UK), `in` (India), etc.
- value of `q` (probably stands for 'search query'), i.e. `education` with your search term. Combine multiple words with a plus sign, e.g. `education+policy` (if your search is for 'Education Policy').

Now the RSS feed button in your browser should've become active because an RSS feed is available for the page. It shows 10 latest news items in the feed, not 5. And the RSS feed URL would look like this:

```
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&q=education&output=rss
```

**Conclusion:** RSS feeds aren't available for **actual** searches, i.e. typing in the search box on Google. You'd have to do it like this.

*(**PS:** Credit goes to the question itself. It would not have occurred to me otherwise.)*

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
&output=rss
https://news.google.com/news/section?cf=all&ned=us&q=education**&output=rss**
```

Comment: This seems fine, but deserves a little additional explanation.

Comment: This works for me. Any way to specify 'Order by date' with this link? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexVPerl, add to your URL this parameter: `as_qdr=h` check this [reference](http://i-tweak.blogspot.com.co/2013/10/google-news-search-parameters-missing.html) for more info, and also, check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The custom RSS feed is in this format:

```
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q={yourquery}&output=rss.
```

For example, `https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=developer&output=rss` returns news about developer.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is somthing like [Google Alerts feeds](http://www.google.com/alerts). You can type a query select the type of data in there and get it delivered via `RSS`. Since they support [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) for that, you will also get results in realtime.

If you want another dataset feel free to also check [Superfeedr's track feeds](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/misc.html#track) which will help you get notified in realtime when keywords are matched across any RSS feed.

Comment: i don't know what the search is ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google disabled the RSS search output in the past few weeks, and I have not found an alternative.  The XML output requires a Google paid account.  I now have to scrape the HTML for what I want.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  The original question was about news "feeds", while my problem is getting RSS results from google News _searches_.

Comment: i'm getting news searches as rss. `https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=whatever`

Comment: Wow, that was very helpful.  I now see that http://news.google.com/news/*feeds* supports RSS output, while http://www.google.com/*search* is the one that just stopped RSS support.  Yeah, no more HTML scraping!

Answer (score -1):

Here's the new way to access Google News RSS feeds:

https://news.google.com/news/rss/search/section/q/{yourquery}